# Converting HTML to Valid String

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, zend-framework

I currently have a PHP project that uses the Zend Framework.  When a user clicks a button, I am using a partial to get the HTML that needs to be added to the page.  The problem is that the HTML seems to be returned as HTML rather than a string:

```
document.getElementById("active_projects").innerHTML='<?php echo $this->partial("project/project/activeprojectstable.phtml", array(
    "headers" => $headers, 
    "active" => $this->active
                        
))?>';
```

`.innerHTML =` takes a string, but the HTML has new lines and special characters that it does not accept. How can I convert the HTML to a valid HTML string?

---

## Update:

For a better idea of the HTML being produced by the partial that is causing the issues, this is what it evaluates to:

[image: error from html]

Comment: You need to change that `=` to a `(` first of all.  `.innerHTML='...);`  instead use `.innerHTML(...)`

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix I don't think so: http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascript-innerHTML.php

Comment: I was thinking jQuery style regardless the extra `)` at the end is still an issue. Maybe not the issue, but an issue none the less.

Comment: Everything in javascript that is bound to var like `var i = 'ABC';` does not have any linebreaks in it! Keep that in Mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try encapsulating your partial into a `script` tag with `type="text/template"`. Browser will not understand what type of script it is, therefore it will not execute it. Nevertheless, you can still access its contents, even if they are multiline.

```
<script type="text/template" id="active_projects_template">
  <?php echo $this->partial("project/project/activeprojectstable.phtml", array(
    "headers" => $headers, 
    "active" => $this->active
  ))?>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // ...
  document.getElementById("active_projects").innerHTML=document.getElementById("active_projects_template").innerHTML;
  // ...
</script>
```

Similar pattern is being used by templates in AngularJS (`type` is set to `text/ng-template`).

- [Exemplary jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lqk3ngo/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try html_entity_decode: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_html_entity_decode.asp

```
<?php
$str = "&lt;&copy; W3S&ccedil;h&deg;&deg;&brvbar;&sect;&gt;";
 echo html_entity_decode($str);
 ?>
```

The HTML output of the code above will be (View Source):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<© W3Sçh°°¦§>
</body>
</html>
```

The browser output of the code above will be:

```
<© W3Sçh°°¦§>
```

Comment: Looks like I'm getting: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token` because the HTML has a new line